# Dispatches occur, but store is only partially updated

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to update my user state for my log in flow. User is part of rootReducer. Session is also, but that state's reducer belongs to the redux-react-session library.

My login flow is: user visits page, enters username and password. User presses Log In form button. On submit, session calls to server and signs user in. During the sign in process, the dispatch for the user state runs.

But after it runs, the user state is what it was before. Sign in clearly succeeded. So session state is populated with new data, and user state is not. Logs throughout indicate that userReducer was called, and that the state it returns conforms to expectation. Is there some special way to connect the userReducer to the store, or update it? Failing code below.

Documentation I found doesn't show if it's necessary to treat rootReducer stores differently from non-combined stores. Also, the login flow relies on the same function to dispatch the two actions, so the issue must be somewhere in the userReducer or action.

Edit: supplied code falls through to default case when it hits userReducer. I confirmed this by setting the default case to supply a different email value. Why is userReducer not accepting the action type UserActions#userAdd returns? And at what point is userReducer even called?

Edit2: debugger placed in userReducer shows that dispatch action does initially reach 'ADD_USER' and returns the proper object, but it does the dispatch several times immediately after and somehow resets the user state just between loading a different page. Is this normal behavior?

```
//rootReducer.js
const reducers = {
  user: userReducer,
  session: sessionReducer
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);




//userReducer.js
function userReducer(state = { email: '', projects: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_USER':
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.user);
    case 'LOGOUT_USER':
       return {email: '', projects: [] };
       case 'EDIT_USER':
         return { email: '', projects: [] };
    case 'DELETE_USER':
      return { email: '', projects: [] };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userReducer;




//LoginContainer.js
//this component calls the failing dispatch
//dispatch is default provided dispatch from connect function
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as sessionActions from '../actions/SessionActions';
import * as userActions from '../actions/UserActions';

...
onSubmit = (e, history) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.dispatch(sessionActions.login(this.state, history, this.props.dispatch, userActions.addUser))

    //addUser({email: this.state.email, projects: []});
  }
...
export default connect(null)(LoginContainer);





//SessionActions.js
//failing code lives here:
//dispatch(addUser(json)); seems to fail somehow
//even though flow is basically the same as session
export const login = (state, history, dispatch, addUser) => {
  return () => {
    return sessionApi.login(state).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
      sessionService.saveSession({ json })
      .then(() => {

        sessionService.saveUser(json)
        .then(() => {
          if (json.email) {
            console.log(state);
            console.log(json);

            dispatch(addUser(json));
            localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(json.email));
            history.push('/');
            //history.go(0);
          }
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
  };
};




//UserActions.js
export const addUser = (user) => {
  console.log(user);
  return {type: 'ADD_USER', user }
}
```

Comment: What is the action payload for ADD_USER? can you verify? What is guess is that the action payload is empty, thus no changes take place

Comment: There's an action called user structured as user: {email: user.email}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The project needed redux-persist so that the state data rehydrates from one page to the next. Session state has its own handling for this functionality.

Code for implementing with combineReducers and redux-react-session and redux-thunk below. I'm still working on refining the merge level.

```
$ npm install redux-persist

//configureStore.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { sessionService } from 'redux-react-session';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // defaults to localStorage for web

import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
sessionService.initSessionService(store);
export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```